# Rails 4, custom messagevalidates_uniqueness_of

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I am validating my model for uniqueness of the day that is selected using the following code:

`validates_uniqueness_of :day, scope: :store`

This works perfectly, but now I am trying to add a custom message for it but would like to convert my :day (int) into a dayname, I feel like I am very close but might be missing something simple.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :day, scope: :store, :message => " already has a target for #{Date::DAYNAMES[%{value}]}."
```

The above code throws an error because %{value} is not evaluating in my code block, is there another way of accessing the value the user has selected?

**Edit**
If I update my message to this:
`"already has a target for %{value}."` I get the correct value appearing, it is an integer. My guess is that I am not accessing the value correctly when I wrap it in a code block:

`#{Date::DAYNAMES[%{value}]}`

Here is my entire model

```
class DailyTarget < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :store

    validates_uniqueness_of :day, scope: :store, :message => " already has a target  for #{Date::DAYNAMES[%{value}]}."
    validates_numericality_of :day, :only_integer => true, :message => "must be a whole number between 1 and 7."
    validates :day, inclusion: { in: 1..7, message: "must be between 1 and 7." }
end
```

as per answer below I have tried `#{Date::DAYNAMES[{{value}}]}` and got this error:

```
app/models/daily_target.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC
app/models/daily_target.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}'
app/models/daily_target.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG
app/models/daily_target.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}'
app/models/daily_target.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG
app/models/daily_target.rb:6: unterminated string meets end of file
app/controllers/daily_targets_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

then tried `#{Date::DAYNAMES[%{value}.to_i]}` this evaluated as "Sunday" (i.e. %{value}.to_i always evaluates to 0

**Thanks to mvidaurre I have found the answer**

My final solution is a custom method, my new model looks like:

```
class DailyTarget < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :store

    validate :must_be_unique

    validates_numericality_of :day, :only_integer => true, :message => "must be a whole number between 1 and 7."
    validates :day, inclusion: { in: 1..7, message: "must be between 1 and 7." }

    def must_be_unique
        if self.class.where(day: day, store: store).exists?
            errors.add(:day, "is invalid - #{store} already has a target for #{Date::DAYNAMES[day]}.")
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: maybe you can start frm here to do your custom validation. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

Comment: The title might be a bit misleading, the problem is not the validation it is getting the message to evaluate correctly `#{Date::DAYNAMES[%{value}]}`

Comment: what is the error you're getting? you should make sure that value is an integer and not a string.

Comment: The eror I am getting is "can't convert String into Integer", this tells me that the `%{value}` segment is not evaluating correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
class DayValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator 
    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
        if record.class.where(attribute => value).exists?
            record.errors[attribute] << " already has a target for #{Date::DAYNAMES[value]}." 
        end
    end

end

validates :day, day: true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#{Date::DAYNAMES[n]}
```

Expect `n` to be an integer. Using `%{value}` you are creating an String. Put then `#{Date::DAYNAMES[value]}`

Comment: I tried that and got `undefined local variable or method `value' for #<Class:0x5501868>`

Comment: Where do you define `value`?

Comment: Use `#{Date::DAYNAMES[{{value}}]}` if that does not work use `#{Date::DAYNAMES[%{value}.to_i]}`

Comment: No luck: `app/models/daily_target.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC`

Comment: Ok. Then try `#{Date::DAYNAMES[self.day]}`

Comment: `#{Date::DAYNAMES[self.day]}` = `undefined method `day' for #<Class:0x4620528>`

Comment: `#{Date::DAYNAMES[%{value}.to_i]}` is giving you which error?

Comment: It is not giving me an error - but it always evaluates to Sunday, Testing with `#{%{value}.to_i}` always evaluates to 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58041/discussion-between-rick-and-mvidaurre).